# PL/SQL procedure to run some statements and then log the result in a table

Tags: plsql

I need to automate the following set of instructions with a pl/sql procedure:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

TRUNCATE TABLE EMP.dept;

INSERT INTO EMP.dept values....;

Commit;
```

Also,I need to log the activity(sucess/failure) into a table EMP.Log.

Can someone help me in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what the columns are in the `EMP.dept` table I would use a procedure defined as:

```
--The parameters to this procedure depend on the fields in EMP.dept
--This example assumes EMP.dept has only 2 VARCHAR fields, but
--the parameter list can easily be modified:
--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_NAME1(INPUT1 IN VARCHAR2, INPUT2 IN VARCHAR2)  AS
    V_FAILURE INTEGER;
BEGIN
    V_FAILURE := 0;
    BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE EMP.dept';
       INSERT INTO EMP.dept (FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES (INPUT1, INPUT2);
       COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        V_FAILURE := 1;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    BEGIN
        --DEPENDING ON THE COLUMNS IN YOUR LOG_TABLE
        --
        INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE(STATUS, RUN_DATE) 
        VALUES (V_FAILURE, SYSDATE);
        COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
    END;

END;
```

Comment: You can avoid having a parameter list by using rec_dept IN EMP.dept%ROWTYPE as the single input parameter, you would then change insert into EMP.dept(field1, field2) values (input1, input2) to insert into EMP.dept values rec_dept.




BIG WARNING; The TRUNCATE command issues an implicit COMMIT so regardless if the second operation in the block fails or succeeds a ROLLBACK will NOT restore the data in the EMP.dept field.

Comment: Thanks Nick!!,In addition to this,if the log table contains column like start time and end time,how can we log these into the table ?

Comment: Thanks Mulander for your comments!!Then,for such case,is there any way to avoid that ?Also,if the log table contains column like start time and end time,how can we log these into the table ?

Comment: Use SYSDATE - that is equivalent to the current date and time.

Comment: But that will only record the start time,my question here is for the end time at which the execution ended?

Comment: Just set the start_time := SYSDATE at the beginning of the procedure and set end_time := SYSDATE at the end of the procedure